# Dataframe merge and create multiple columns with multiple matches

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, merging-data

I have two pandas dataframes. DF1 has columns A B and C. DF2 has columns B and C. I want to create DF3 with columns A B C D and E.

I want column A B and C to be the same and in the same order as column A B and C in DF1. Then I want column D to be the values in DF2 column B when DF2 B and C both match DF1 B and C. Then I want DF3 column E to be the values in DF2 column B when DF2 column B matches DF1 B but the column C amounts do not match.

To summarize:

Columns:

A - same as DF1 A

B - same as DF1 B

C - same as DF1 C

D - the values of DF2 B when both B and C match DF1.

E - the values of DF2B when only B matches DF1 and c does not.

Thanks in advance!

Here is an example:

[DF1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOEj9.png)

[DF2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfanm.png)

[DF3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJFKT.png)

Here is the same example in text:

| DF1: |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C |
| AAA | 123 | 456 |
| BBB | 789 | 888 |
| CCC | 999 | 111 |
| DDD | 555 | 444 |

| DF2: |  |
| --- | --- |
| B | C |
| 123 | 456 |
| 789 | 888 |
| 789 | 900 |
| 789 | 950 |
| 999 | 111 |
| 555 | 000 |
| 555 | 444 |

| DF3: |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | D | E |
| AAA | 123 | 456 | 456 | nan |
| BBB | 789 | 888 | 888 | 900, 950 |
| CCC | 999 | 111 | 111 | nan |
| DDD | 555 | 444 | 444 | 000 |

I have tried to do a merge like the following:
df1.merge(df2['C'].astype(str).groupby(df2['B']).agg(', '.join), on='B', how='left;).fillna('0') which has worked when I want to match on one column (for example B), and pull in the information in C.  But I am not familiar with how to pull in multiple columns when one needs to match twice, and one needs to match only once, discluding any that match in both columns.

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can offer relevant advice.

Comment: Can you now make your example [**reproducible**](/q/20109391/16343464)? Use text, not images, we can't copy data from images.

Comment: I added an example. I am adding what I have tried right now as well.

Comment: I think I have an answer to your problem but I can't test it without a reproducible example

Comment: I created a table with the example just now, thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tested the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on "B", then assign "D"/"E" depending on the equality of the two "C" columns. Finally, [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) to reshape your DataFrame:

```
out = (df1
  .merge(df2, on='B', how='left', suffixes=(None, '_'))
  .assign(col=lambda d: np.where(d['C'].eq(d['C_']), 'D', 'E'))
  .pivot_table(index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns='col', values='C_',
               aggfunc=lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)))
  .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C    D        E
0  AAA  123  456  456      NaN
1  BBB  789  888  888  900,950
2  CCC  999  111  111      NaN
3  DDD  555  444  444      000
```